# remove files in directory and print the deleted files name

Tags: linux, find, echo, delete-file

I want to remove files in directory except a specific file and print a message if files remove.

```
find . ! -name 'name' -type f -exec echo 'removed files:' rm -v -f {} +
```

When I run this command it prints:

```
removed files: rm -v -f ./aaavl ./aaavlpo
```

I want to print putput like:

```
removed files:
./aaavl
./aaavlpo
```

How should I do this?

Comment: If you remove `echo 'removed files:'` it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `find` in a Bash loop to modify the output.

Given:

```
$ ls -1
file 1
file 2
file 3
file 4
file 5
```

You can still loop and negate with `find` as desired. Just use Bash to delete and report:

```
$ find . ! -name *3 -type f | while read fn; do echo "removing: $fn";     rm "$fn"; done
removing: ./file 1
removing: ./file 2
removing: ./file 5
removing: ./file 4

$ ls -1
file 3
```

That loop will work for filenames with spaces OTHER THAN `\n`.

If there is a possibility of file names with `\n` in them, use `xargs` with a `NUL` delimiter:

```
$ find . ! -name *3 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -I% bash -c ' echo "%" ; rm "%" ;'
```

And add the header `echo "removed files:"`  above the loop or `xargs` pipe as desired.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's not a better way, but ...

1 - Save the file names in .txt:
  find -name 'name' -type f -exec echo >> test.txt {} \;

2 after saving the files, executing the deletion of the files
  find. ! -name 'name' -type f -exec rm -f {} +